# How do I get the column number from a dataframe which contains specific strings?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` with 7 columns and I have a list `z` containing multiple strings.
I want a dataframe containing only the columns in `df` which contain the sting from `z`.

```
df <- data.frame("a_means","b_means","c_means","d_means","e_mean","f_means","g_means")
z <- c("a_m","c_m","f_m")
```

How do I get the column number of the `z` strings in `df`? Or how do I get a dataframe with only the columns which contains the `z` strings.

What I want is:

```
print(df)
"a_means" "c_m" "f_m"
```

What I tried:

```
match(a, names(df)
```

and

```
df[,which(colnames(df) %in% colnames(df[ ,grepl(z,names(df)])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df[,match(z, substring(colnames(df), 1, 3))]
```

Comment: clever solution!

Answer (score 3):

With base R:

```
z <- paste(z, collapse = "|")
df[, grepl(z, names(df))]      # you could use grep as well
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine the search patterns and use that as a pattern for `stringr::str_detect()` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(a_means = "a_means",
                 b_means = "b_means",
                 c_means = "c_means",
                 d_means = "d_means",
                 e_means = "e_means",
                 f_means = "f_means",
                 g_means = "g_means"
                 )

z <- c("a_m","c_m","f_m")

z <- paste(z, collapse = "|")

df %>% select_if(str_detect(names(df), z))
#>   a_means c_means f_means
#> 1 a_means c_means f_means
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(contains(z))
```

Check out `help("starts_with")`. You can also match to a starting prefix with `starts_with()` among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` and `matches` to subest the columns based on `z`

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("a_means","b_means","c_means","d_means","e_mean","f_means","g_means")
z <- c("a_m","c_m","f_m")

df %>% 
  select(matches(z))
#>   X.a_means. X.c_means. X.f_means.
#> 1    a_means    c_means    f_means
```